# Double click word JavaScript window.getSelection in two INS tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML is:

```
<p><ins data-id="1">111</ins><ins data-id="2">222</ins></p>
```

The output of this code is:

> [image]

If I double click the word, it's selecting the complete word, like this:

> [image]

But I want to select the letters based on the INS tag `data-id`

Ex:- if I double click the `111` I want to select only `111` like this:

> [image]

How to modify the default double click selection to JavaScript selection?

I tried the following code:

```
var containerid = $(e.currentTarget);
if (window.getSelection) {
   var range = document.createRange();
   range.selectNode(containerid);
   var sel = window.getSelection()
   sel.removeAllRanges();
   sel.addRange(range);
}
```

But it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```html
<p><ins data-id="1">111</ins>&#8203;<ins data-id="2">222</ins></p>
```

You could just put a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) between them: `&#8203;`